How to convert tabs from rounded to square in Sublime Text?
I want to convert rounded tabs into square tabs in Sublime Text 4, just like tabs in VSCode.

Is it even possible in Sublime Text? I'm using Default theme and my custom color scheme.
Is Sublime Text using color or some background image for those rounded corners?
What settings I need to add in my theme file?
